# Is there any way to reduce UV fading on a hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, uv-exposure

I've seen a lot of old hardwood floors where the owner moved a rug that had been there for years, and the wood under the rug was noticeably brighter, having been shielded from UV degradation. Is there any way to prevent this phenomenon? Will modern Low-E windows that block UV radiation do the job? Are there any stains or sealants that are UV-blocking?

Comment: Keep the blinds closed?  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-E windows will go a great job, and help with many energy losses.

A rug will always be better than just about anything, covered places on just about anything will take less abuse than uncovered surfaces.

Minwax has always been my favorite for anything I can put it on.

Their naming conventions are not always the most clever.

'Minwax Super Fast-Drying Polyurethane for Floors' is a product that will work for you.

They make a number of other products for coating hardwood floors.

Sherwin-Williams has never led me astray either.

Working on wood floors sucks, best of luck to you

Comment: Agreed. Wood floors are my 'Frenemy'. They look great, and I love having them around, but we shouldn't work together. On a productive note, less invasively I believe there are some floor polished/waxes that offer marginal UV protection, if applied regularly.

Comment: Sure, a rug will protect the floor from fading, but in that case, why bother with hardwood floors at all? No point in having them if you "protect" them so well that you never enjoy them - put in wall-to wall carpet, save a pile of money. IMHO part of the positive value of real wood is that it does change and age gracefully.

Comment: Ecnerwal - My house has wonderful hardwood floors, and I agree they should be shown. I do not think that the options are rugs - or - no rugs. But rather one of function and esthetics. I have a rug under my dining room table, including the area where the chairs are when leaving the table. For me, a rug here is better than leaving it to the abuse of being without a rug. There is still floor showing on all the edges of the room, but the floor is protected from the daily abuse of the chairs. I also have rugs in most of our closets. Different people, different thoughts, the way it should be :)